# android: doesn't work calender in Thread on Service

Tags: android, multithreading, service, calendar

I newbie in android. I have a little problem. I have code like this in service class :

```
public void doWork() throws Exception{

    mHandler.post(new Runnable(){

        public void run(){

            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            cal.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());

            cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 21);
            cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 14);

            long noon_start = cal.getTimeInMillis();

            cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 21);
            cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 16);

            long noon_end = cal.getTimeInMillis();
            long now = System.currentTimeMillis();//current time

            if(now > noon_start && now < noon_end)
            {

                if (show.active==false){
                    showIt();
                }


            }else{ //close activitis

                if (show.active==true){

                    sendBroadcast(new Intent("close"));
                }

            }
        }

}); 

}
```

i want to if time 21:14 - 21:16, show new activity. Else, close activity. It works, but when show new activity, 1 second after that, it close. Show and close again. Continues like that . .

i try with this, it works,

```
    Date dt = new Date();
    int minutes = dt.getMinutes();

            if (minutes%2==0){


                if (show.active==false){
                    showIt();
                }


            }else{ //close activitis

                if (show.active==true){

                    sendBroadcast(new Intent("close"));

                }
}
```

What must i do?
Please help

Comment: how do you start the thread?

Comment: Can you post your logcat please?

Comment: @apm: it works, no error. it show, but 1 second after that close. 1 second after that show again, and close again